# Drawing line towards the center using point

Tags: android, math, geometry

I have got some points which make a circle. I want another point for each point such that if  we draw a line using those two points, the line should point towards the center of the circle. I have angle of each point with respect to the center of the circle. I have added a snapshot for clarity. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let DIST be the distance you want between the center of the circle and the point you plot. Then, if ANGLE is the angle between the center and the point on the outside (in radians).

x= DIST * Math.cos(ANGLE),
y= DIST * Math.sin(ANGLE)

Comment: Thanks. I tried this. This draws a line from the center to the distance away from center. I want that I draw a line from a given point towards the center lets say of length 10 pixels as I have shown in pic like a clock which has small lines near the digits.